# when to use "and" statement in informix DB

Tags: informix

i have a problem in my SQL statement where the situation is I need to choose the data which have to meet several criteria.

Question: How to determine existing old company - Lodgement of (F557 & F559) or  (F558 & F559) or (F557 & F55)

my SQL :

```
SELECT * from roclodgingdetails 
WHERE(vchformtrx='559' AND vchformtrx='557') 
OR (vchformtrx='558' AND vchformtrx='559') 
OR (vchformtrx='557' AND vchformtrx='55')
```

but this statement give me the result empty, even there is data meet the condition.

Answer (score 3):

`vchformtrx` in a single row cannot have multiple values at once, for example;

```
WHERE (vchformtrx='559' AND vchformtrx='557')
```

...would require vchformtrx in a single row to have both the value `559` AND `557` *at the same time* to be true and return a result. The same goes for the other `AND` conditions. Using `OR` on 3 false conditions will still always result in false.

Your quoted question does not quite give me enough info on what the condition should really be, but - in short - you won't get any hints since your current condition can never be true.